# Liferay: menus' order changes arbitrarily

Tags: liferay

I am really going crazy with this problem! In the top navigation bar of my site I have 4 menus: Menu 1, Menu 2, Menu 3, Menu 4 for example. Since yesterday, after I added a new page (which I deleted later), the menus have taken a reverse order, that is Menu 4, Menu 3 and so on. From control panel, I reorder them the way it should be, but when I click save button to leave the control panel, the orders again change, this time randomly.

Any idea why this happens? I am using Liferay 6.1.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Any hooks you have deployed which may be conflicting with this? Try to create a new site and see if this happens in a new Site or not? Are you using Site template to create sites?

Comment: No errors in console at all and no hooks. I just created a page and moved the link of the page in the site pages one level higher; then this happened. The templates are custom templates I have built myself. I came upon this link which considers this problem a Liferay bug: http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-26509. Does this  mean I should install some patch to solve this?

Comment: The above issue seems to be solved in 6.1 GA1. Though I have found another issue with Site-templates. If you have a site-template with 2 pages ST1 & ST2 and create a site with 2 pages SA & SB using this template. Then you won't be able to change the order to ST1, SA, ST2, SB. It seems that all the site-template pages will always be togather, you can't have a page between the pages of a Site-template.

Comment: Thanks Rasabihari Kumar for your comments. Managed to handle this as in the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by going to the database and changing/updating the menus' priority value. Now it is as it should be. 
For some reason at some point when the ordering had gone wrong, that setting had persisted in the database, no matter how many times I changed the orders through the control panel and saved it.